# How to get the index of 2nd smallest value in a numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minimum

```
a=array([[ 0.  ,  0.71,  5.66,  3.61,  4.24,  3.2 ],
   [ 0.71,  0.  ,  4.95,  2.92,  3.54,  2.5 ],
   [ 5.66,  4.95,  0.  ,  2.94,  1.41,  2.5 ],
   [ 3.61,  2.92,  2.94,  0.  ,  1.  ,  0.5 ],
   [ 4.24,  3.54,  1.41,  1.  ,  0.  ,  1.12],
   [ 3.2 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  0.5 ,  1.12,  0.  ]])

row,column=np.unravel_index(a.argmin(), a.shape)
```

returns row=0, column=0. I want the row and column of the 2nd smallest value that us row=3, column =5 or row=5, column =3.

Comment: so 1.41 is the second smallest value?

Comment: No, smallest value is 0.5. @ManishSaraswat

Comment: why is this question closed? the question it is marked duplicated to is for 1-d array, which is very different.